# SuperSlicer model malfunction?

Tags: 3d-models, slicing, superslicer

I just want to print this [shower curtain ring](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:26345):

[image]

For some reason SuperSlicer doens't like the circles and after slicing the model looks like this in preview.[image]

What is the issue with the slicer? Is there any setting that I might have and ruin the model?

Thanks

Comment: Using the link, I downloaded the single ring and Meshmixer says there are no flaws in the model. PrusaSlicer also slices the file without complications. Have you tried another slicer in order to have additional data?

Comment: @fred_dot_u I removed the preset that I originally had and reimport it and everything is fine now. Possible that the config got corrupted

Comment: Good deal. Consider to create an answer to your own question, give it a day and mark it correct with the check mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment I didn't find the exactly what option from config did this but after reimporting the preset everything is back to normal(possible something got corrupted in the preset or the app, I don't know for sure).
I will still research to see what caused the issue for feature.
Thanks all